# SUM cell values based on multiple condition - either A column or B column cell is true. Any of the two. But not always both conditions are true

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010

In my excel sheet I have 3 columns as :

```
A        B    C
===================
XYZ      N    9
ABC      N    1
MNO      N    3
D             13
D        D    7
D        D    9
D             1
```

Now, From these sheet I want sum of all cells in C column where either value in A or B column's cell is 'D'.

something like : if(a='D' or b='D') then sum+=C

Here, for case SUM(where cell value is 'D' in columns A or B) will be 30.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you had those values in cells A1:C7, this should do the trick:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C1:C7*(A1:A7="D"))+SUMPRODUCT(C1:C7*(B1:B7="D"))-SUMPRODUCT(C1:C7*(A1:A7="D")*(B1:B7="D"))
```

To explain the formula, it is:
(Sum of C where A = "D") + (Sum of C where B = "D") - (Sum of C where both A = "D" and B = "D")

The reason for the last part is to avoid double counting.

Comment: Thanks @iambasil; but the no. of records in the sheet are not fixed. Every time its different. So, I want a solution which works irrespective of limited rang; instead it should work for entire column.

Comment: No problem, then just delete all the row numbers (e.g. A:A instead of A1:A7). There are other ways of automatically calculating the height of the range if you do not want to reference the entire column (using the offset formula), but using A:A / B:B / C:C should be sufficient for what you've described.